# How to keep specific words when preprocessing words for NLP?(str.replace & regex)

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I want to remove digit except '3d', this word.
I've tried some methods but failed.
Please look through my simple code below:

```py
s = 'd3 4 3d'
rep_ls = re.findall('([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]*)', s)

>> ['3', '4', '3d']

for n in rep_ls:
    if n == '3d':
        continue
    s = s.replace(n, '')

>> s = 'd  d'
>> expected = 'd 3d'
```

Comment: what if string is like `123d12312` or `3d1231` or `123d` ? what should be desired output ?

Comment: @CodeManiac I still expect to return 3d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, this expression,

```
(?i)(3d)\b|(\D+)|\d+
```

might work OK with `re.sub` of `\1\2`.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3L7nxM/1/)

If `3D` would be also undesired, which we are assuming otherwise here, then `(?i)` can be safely removed:

```
(3d)\b|(\D+)|\d+
```

Anything else other than `3d` that you wish to keep would go in the first capturing group:

```
(3d|4d|anything_else)\b|(\D+)|\d+
```

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r'(?i)(3d)\b|(\D+)|\d+'
string = '''d3 4 3d'''

print(re.sub(regex, r'\1\2', string))
```

#### Output

```
d 3d
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/zk3PHt/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Prints out `d  d` - [Demo](https://repl.it/repls/CleverElasticBackend)

Comment: `>> expected = 'd 3d'`

Answer (score 2):

To remove all digits except the word `3d` you could use a negative lookahead `(?!` to assert what is directly to the right is not 3d between word boundaries `\b`

Then match 1+ digits `\d+`

In the replacement use an empty string.

```
(?!\b3d\b)\d+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tny3Pw/1)

Answer (score 1):

You're very close, you simply need to split the value by space and then loop over the value if the value is `3d` don't change it else change it

```
import re;
s = 'd3 4 3d'
rep_ls = re.split(r'\s+', s)

final = ''
for n in rep_ls:
    if n == '3d':
        final +=' 3d'
        continue
    final +=  ' ' + re.sub(r'\d+','',n)


print(final)
```

Trim the string in the end to remove the extra space or use an if statement to not add space when index is `0`

---

Or you can use dictionary and join them later

```
import re;
s = 'd3 4 3d'
rep_ls = re.split(r'\s+', s)

final = []
for n in rep_ls:
    if n == '3d':
        final.append(n)
        continue
    final.append(re.sub(r'\d+','',n))

final = " ".join(final)    
print(final)
```

---

Output is  >>  `d 3d`